# Install angular schematics on mac: command not found

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I'm trying to install the schematics-cli for angular on a mac (sierra 10.12.6) but I get command not found errors when I try to run it in the command line.

I install it globally with:

`npm install -g @angular-devkit/schematics-cli`

and can see it listed as a global install as

`npm list --depth=0 -g`

gives

`/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.1.0/lib
├── @angular-devkit/schematics-cli@0.8.1
├── @angular/cli@6.1.5
├── @schematics/schematics@0.7.5
├── npm@6.3.0
├── rxjs@6.3.1
├── rxjs-tslint@0.1.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY tslint@^5.0.0
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev || >=2.9.0-dev`

However, if I try to run a command e.g.

`schematics --help`
 
I get

`-bash: schematics: command not found`

Any suggestions for what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for Mac:

Open

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

add this to the file:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit:$PATH"
```